# Want to Print data from Data Set (tuples) in Django template?

Tags: python, django

There are response from Django query

Data format is :

```
(237146768, u'43 S LUBEC RD', u'LUBEC', u'ME') (455414678, u'PO BOX 41', u'LUBEC', u'ME')
```

**Want to print like This in my template :**

```
 - 237146768 
 - 43 S LUBEC RD 
 - UBEC 
 - ME

------------

 - 455414678
 - PO BOX 41
 - LUBEC
 - ME
```

Comment: follow this guide https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/template-response/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need django templates for this. Just use simple string formatting.

```
data = [(237146768, u'43 S LUBEC RD', u'LUBEC', u'ME'), (455414678, u'PO BOX 41', u'LUBEC', u'ME')]
record_separator = '\n\n------------\n\n'
items = ('\n'.join('- %s' % item for item in tup) for tup in data)
print(record_separator.join(items))
```

https://repl.it/Kdbv/0

Answer (score 0):

an example in your view is like this:

```
list_data = [
    (237146768, u'43 S LUBEC RD', u'LUBEC', u'ME'),
    (455414678, u'PO BOX 41', u'LUBEC', u'ME')
]
context = {'list_data': list_data}
return render(request, 'templatename.html', context}
```

and then in your template:

```
<ul>
  {% for data in list_data %}
    <li>{{ data.0 }}</li>
    <li>{{ data.1 }}</li>
    <li>{{ data.2 }}</li>
    <li>{{ data.3 }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```